# Swagger-UI Maximum call stack size exceeded -> Backreference

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

When calling my swagger.json from the swagger-ui I get an error:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

I guess it is because I have

`Token` which has an owner of Type `User`

`User` which has a Token of Type `Token`

When using the online-version of the swagger editior it can resolve the types. How can I configure swagger to resolve the types correctly?

The full `swagger.json`

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "description": "Descr",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "title": "Skeleton"
    },
    "host": "1.1.1.1:11",
    "basePath": "/api",
    "tags": [{
            "name": "auth"
        }
    ],
    "schemes": ["http"],
    "paths": {
        "/auth/local": {
            "post": {
                "tags": ["auth"],
                "summary": "Authenticates User",
                "description": "This auths only local users",
                "operationId": "authenticateUser",
                "consumes": ["application/json"],
                "produces": ["application/json"],
                "parameters": [{
                        "in": "body",
                        "name": "body",
                        "required": false,
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/Credentials"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "successful operation",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/AuthResponse"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/auth/ldap": {
            "post": {
                "tags": ["auth"],
                "operationId": "authenticateLdapUser",
                "produces": ["application/json"],
                "parameters": [{
                        "in": "body",
                        "name": "body",
                        "required": false,
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/Credentials"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "default": {
                        "description": "successful operation"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "AuthResponse": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "issued": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "responseType": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["RESPONSE", "ERROR", "UNAUTHORIZED", "OK"]
                },
                "responseDescription": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "accessToken": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Token"
                },
                "resourceName": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "Note": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "content": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "modified": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date-time"
                }
            }
        },
        "Token": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "expirationDate": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "issued": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "expired": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "owner": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/User"
                }
            }
        },
        "User": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "username": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "password": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "email": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "displayName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "notes": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Note"
                    }
                },
                "accessToken": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Token"
                }
            }
        },
        "Credentials": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "user": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "password": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which versions of Swagger UI and Swagger Editor?

Comment: Both newest, UI: v3.0.8 and Swagger Editor which is online: http://editor.swagger.io/#/

Comment: This looks like issue [3012](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3012), which is "fixed, pending next release of swagger-js."

Comment: I have this same issue, but with the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore nuget package

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I removed **format: date-time** and the error is gone.
Still I don't know what causes the error. But without that format everything goes ok.

Answer (score 0):

In FastAPI which uses Swagger UI, I was receiving the same error. I updated the FastAPI package to get the last version of Swagger UI and then set the value of 'syntaxHighlight' to False, like below:

```
app = FastAPI(swagger_ui_parameters={'syntaxHighlight': False})
```

Just search how you can set this param directly in Swagger UI. This may fix your issue.